# 1 page javascript techniques, is it possible to create an iframe and dump data in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When creating a single page type website that is purely ajax driven, do people create iframes, and then dump javascript objects that contain cached data?

This way if you reload your main page, you can still access cached data?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an iframe for this.  Typically you will change the innerHTML property of some element on your page.  This way there is no page reloading, and you can maintain whatever state you need.

For example (from [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
}
</script>
<p>Welcome to the site <b id='boldStuff'>dude</b> </p> 
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a modern browser (IE 8+, Chrome, Firefox), why don't you use [HTML 5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)?